# Create an Azure Datadog resource with ARM Templates

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, datadog

I am trying to create a Datadog resource on Azure using an ARM Template. I've set the parameters that I *think* I need, based on the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.datadog/2022-06-01/monitors?pivots=deployment-language-arm-template). However, when I deploy, I get this unhelpful error:

```json
{
  "code": "ResourceCreationFailed",
  "message": "ResourceCreationFailed: Bad Request"
}
```

This is what my resource template looks like:

```json
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Datadog/monitors",
  "apiVersion": "2022-06-01",

  "name": "[variables('datadogName')]",
  "location": "[parameters('location')]",

  "sku": {
    "name": "payg_v2_Monthly"
  },

  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },

  "properties": {
    "monitoringStatus": "Enabled",
    "userInfo": "[parameters('datadogContact')]",
    "datadogOrganizationProperties": {
      "name": "[variables('datadogName')]"
    }
  }
}
```

Where:

- `datadogName` is constructed to look something like `<PREFIX>-<LOCATION>-<PROJECT>-dd-<ENV>`. (It is 25 characters long, if that's the problem.)
- `datadogContact` is an object, with `name`, `emailAddress` and `phoneNumber` keys.
- `location` is set to `westus2`, which I believe is the only available location. (Note: The resource group is in `eastus2`.)

If it matters, there is one other Datadog resource under this subscription, with the same SKU. (I believe it was created manually, through the Azure Portal.) I don't know if you are limited to one instance per subscription...

Is there a limit, or is there just something wrong with my template?

---

**Edit** I retried my template using the Azure Portal's "Deploy a Custom Template" service and it worked just fine. When I get the error above, the template is deployed as part of a pipeline, running as a Service Principal. Is there something about the SP account that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by checking the resource group deployments in the Azure Portal for any error clues.

ResourceCreationFailed: Bad Request, i've usually found is an error i get when somethings not quite right in my template. So iterating on your template a little more might yield success.

I've not been able to repro, as I don't use datadog. However my bicep code (why are you using ARM json btw, bicep makes ARM authoring so much nicer), doesn't get past the validation stage.

```
resource dd 'Microsoft.Datadog/monitors@2022-06-01' = {
  name: 'dd1'
  location: 'westus2'
  properties: {
    datadogOrganizationProperties: {
      name: 'Microsoft'

    }
    monitoringStatus: 'Disabled'
    userInfo: {
      emailAddress: 'gobyers@microsoft.com'
      name: 'Gordon'
      phoneNumber: '555-555-5555'
    }
  }
  sku: { name:'payg_v2_Monthly'}
}
```

```
Inner Errors: 
{"code": "BadRequest", "message": "SaaS Purchase Payment Check Failed as validationResponse was {\"isEligible\":false,\"errorMessage\":\"Purchase has failed because we couldn't find a valid payment method associated with your Azure subscription. Please use a different Azure subscription or add\\\\\\\\update current payment method for this subscription and retry.\"}"}
```

Comment: Thanks. I did get the error response from the Resource Group deployment, in the Portal; what I posted in the original question is literally all it says :( Validation errors like you're getting seem to be eaten by my pipeline, so I'll deploy it manually to see what it comes back with... (BTW: I _would_ use Terraform, or Bicep if needs be, but the powers-that-be cannot be convinced to migrate from ARM Templates.)

Comment: ...Hmm, manual deployment (i.e., using the "Deploy a custom template" resource in the Portal) works just fine.